# Hidden session Id in MVC Master Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sessionid

I have an MVC application, and I need to create and store a unique session Id for each application instance. In standard ASP.NET this is easy, I would have simply added a hidden field in the master page and stored a Guid there on the first Page_Load.

However, there is not code behind in MVC, and I also believe that you can't implement a controller for a master page OR create a strongly typed view master page.

Anyone know an easy way around this? I'm just playing around with MVC for the first time so be gentle if what I'm asking seems stupidly simple.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about ASP.NET sessions or are you reinventing some custom concept because ASP.NET sessions are normally tracked by cookies and are unique to each user and application?

Comment: No it's just something I am creating myself. I need to persist a few objects for the lifetime of an instance of my application. The way I plan to do this is by caching them, using a unique session Id as the cache key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to persist a few objects for the lifetime of an instance of your application I would recommend you using the built-in [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx) object or [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.application.aspx). If those objects need to be specific to each user then use the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx) object.

Comment: Thanks, I have just used the Session object, this has solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why not store this in a cookie?